# cannot use copy command over zip files in S3toRedshift data loading

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I want to copy data from s3 files to redshift database using copy command.

Normally data from a simple excel sheet was easily copied to a database using this simple [copy command](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_loading-tables-from-s3.html)

I tried to simply load data from one zip file for testing purpose, but it failed

```
copy media.DFPActivity from 's3://bucketname/myfolder/file_01.gz' 
credentials 'xxxxxxxx'
delimiter '^';
null as '\000';
```

But I have zip files instead of normal excel files. so can anybody let me know how to extract and copy the data fast into redshift

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `GZIP` to the `COPY` command.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_loading-gzip-compressed-data-files-from-S3.html